# MTA breaks restart of server

Tags: linux, debian

After a reboot the system can't get back online

I have tried several times to reboot, but it always stops here.. The screen have been like this for 30 min so I dont think it will ever get past this

How to solve it? I can access the server in rescue mode.. Is it possible to completely disable MTA at startup in a simpe way?

Or a way to troubleshoot and solve the problem? The most important thing is that the server comes back online :)

[image]

## update

[image]

Comment: What did you change compared to your earlier question? Did you check if the system works anyway (there is no error message, just `OK` signs) and if you can get to a login screen on another console (usually with `Ctrl+number`)?

Comment: I disabled some nginx stuff.. I got an error about ssl..

Answer (score 1):

You have to boot into single user mode. Your system will boot without any daemon. From there you will be able to prevent MTA to start at boot.

### From [Redhat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html) :

> One of the advantages of single-user mode is that you do not need a
>   boot diskette or CD-ROM; however, it does not give you the option to
>   mount the file systems as read-only or not mount them at all.
>
> If your system boots, but does not allow you to log in when it has
>   completed booting, try single-user mode.
>
> In single-user mode, your computer boots to runlevel 1. Your local
>   file systems are mounted, but your network is not activated. You have
>   a usable system maintenance shell. Unlike rescue mode, single-user
>   mode automatically tries to mount your file system; do not use
>   single-user mode if your file system can not be mounted successfully.
>   You can not use single-user mode if the runlevel 1 configuration on
>   your system is corrupted.
>
> On an x86 system using GRUB as the boot loader, use the following
>   steps to boot into single-user mode:
>
> 1. If you have a GRUB password configured, type p and enter the password
> 2. Select Red Hat Enterprise Linux with the version of the kernel that you wish to boot and type a to append the line.
> 3. Go to the end of the line and type single as a separate word (press the [Spacebar] and then type single). Press [Enter] to exit
>      edit mode.
> 4. Back at the GRUB screen, type b to boot into single-user mode.
>
> On an x86 system using LILO as the boot loader, at the LILO boot
>   prompt (if you are using the graphical LILO, you must press [Ctrl]-[x]
>   to exit the graphical screen and go to the boot: prompt) type:
>
> ```
> linux single
> ```
>
> For all other platforms, specify single as a kernel parameter at the
>   boot prompt.

Comment: The server is remote so I cant to that

Comment: How do you connect to the machine ?

Comment: @clarkk: You can do this in the remote console you did the screenshot in, or at least you should be able to.

Comment: ok, så what to I do when I boot up the system? do I have to press a key or something? :)

Comment: When you boot the system, once you get to grub screen juste follow instructions above it should do the trick.

Comment: have updated my question.. is it this screen?

Comment: It is not really what I expected but it could works what does extended menu contains ?